# KerasRl ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 9, 9)

Tags: python, tensorflow, sudoku, openai-gym, keras-rl

I made an env with Gym for Sudoku puzzle and I want to train an AI on it using KerasRL (I've removed the step reset and render method of the environment to not have too much code for StackOverflow).
I use a Flatten and 3 dense layers for my model and compile it with Adam.
I get a error when I try to compile it because the shape isn't the right one and i don't get why :

```py
     from gym import Env
     from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box
     import numpy as np
     import random
     
     from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
     from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Input
     from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
     from numpy.linalg.linalg import double
     from numpy.core.numeric import ones
     
     class Sudoku(Env):
           #Fonction d'initialisaion
     def __init__(self):
               #Soit on met une case fixé et il y a 9 actions possibles (mettre un num de 1 à 9), sur la grille générale il y a 81 cases disponibles et 9 numéros possibles par case ->729
     self.action_space = Discrete(729)
     
               #81 cases qui prennent des valeurs entres 0 (case vide pour 0) et 9, le produit cartésien des deux donnent bien le nombre de grilles possibles au sudoku je pense
               #chaque case est représenté par une case de tableau, le premier array correspond a la borne inferieur prise par chaque case (0) et le deuxieme par la borne sup 9, ça fait enormément d'état possibles
     self.observation_space = Box(low= 0,high= 9, shape=(9,9),dtype=int)
     
               #definition de l'état de départ que des zeros dans les 81 cases (vides)
     self.state = np.zeros((9,9),dtype=int)
     
     
             #fonction application d'action
     def step(self,action):
     return self.state , reward , done , info
     
     def render(self, mode):      
     
     def reset(self):
     return self.state
     
     def build_model(states,actions):
     model=Sequential()
     model.add(Input(shape=states))
     model.add(Flatten())
     model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dense(100,activation='relu'))
     model.add(Dense(actions,activation='linear'))
     return model
     
     from rl.agents import DQNAgent
     from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
     from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
     
     def build_agent(model,actions):
     policy= BoltzmannQPolicy()
     memory= SequentialMemory(limit=50000,window_length=1)
     agent= DQNAgent(model=model,memory=memory,policy=policy,nb_actions=actions,nb_steps_warmup=10,target_model_update=1e-2)
     return agent
     
     env=Sudoku()
     states=env.observation_space.shape
     print(states)
     actions=env.action_space.n
     model = build_model(states,actions)
     model.summary()
     agent = build_agent(model,actions)
     agent.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3),metrics=['mae'])
     agent.fit(env,nb_steps=20000,visualize=False,verbose=1)
```

I get this error :

> Training for 20000 steps ... Interval 1 (0 steps performed)
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 agent.compile(Adam(lr=1e-3),metrics=['mae'])
> ----> 2 agent.fit(env,nb_steps=20000,visualize=False,verbose=1)
>
> 7 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py
> in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis,
> exception_prefix)
> 569         shape = shapes[i]
> 570         if len(data_shape) != len(shape):
> --> 571           raise ValueError('Error when checking ' + exception_prefix +
> 572                            ': expected ' + names[i] + ' to have ' +
> 573                            str(len(shape)) + ' dimensions, but got array '
>
> ```
> ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 9, 9)
> ```

Comment: I’m very interested in your development. I don’t know anything about ML or RL, but I started researching on the subject. I've already developed an Android app which is based on the coding of the algorithms relative to different solving techniques of a sudoku puzzle. Now I would like to develop an AI-based solver. By that I mean a solver that mimics the way a human solve a sudoku puzzle. To be continued.

Comment: Continued. I can't specifically answer your question but I can share my thoughts on an AI-based solver and my experience in the coding of the solving algorithms. Have you find the answer to the current problem? If not, could you tell me what is the objective of your development; implement an equivalent of the backtracking algorithm or something else?

Comment: try this:`build_model(env.observation_space.shape[1:],actions)`

Comment: @mostafaamiri Thanks for your reply but it unfortunately didn't work

Comment: it would work ```Input(shape=(1,)+states)```